# WPF multipage Listview printing when using GroupStyle

Tags: wpf, listview, printing, groupstyle

I have coded up a `ListView` report using xaml, mvvm and it works just fine.
The xaml code deploys `ListView.GroupStyle` and the resulting report has a group header, items listing and group totals and counts.
It looks like this:
[image]

I would like to print this same report to the printer.  It is multipage and the groups alone could span more than a page, depending on the reporting date span.  I would also want to show the column headers at the top of each printed page.

I have read (and practiced) printing ListView reports before to a FixedPage / Fixed Document and calculating the item source for each page to spread the printed report over multiple pages.

This time because I am using the groupings, the problems appear more difficult?  I cannot see how to calculate the item source for each page.   I’m thinking I need to somehow construct the report as a single unbound (no page size restriction) ListView, pluck out the ListViewItems and then use those items to construct my report.

I have read [solutions using FlowDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931925/wpf-printing-multipage-invoice-via-flowdocument-paginator-and-fixeddocument), but do not see an answer there?

Can anyone give me some ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is advice in the acepted answer to StackOverflow link you quoted:

> It turned out that the flowdocument / XPS method was a completely
>   wrong headed way of approaching this task, and in fact the built in
>   RDLC reports allowed us to achieve everything we needed for our
>   invoice documents, in a relatively straight forward manner.

This is the route I would take.

Here is a link to a CodeProject article which prints a datagrid with repeating headers, pretty much what you are asking, if you still want to continue with your oirignal approach:

[CodeProject - Custom Data Grid Document Paginator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138233/Custom-Data-Grid-Document-Paginator)

And there are several good answers with other approaches in this StackOverflow question -

[StackOverflow - Whats the best approach to printing reporting from wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180746/whats-the-best-approach-to-printing-reporting-from-wpf)